# Doctrine entity creation strategy

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

When working with entities in Doctrine it's very obvious to add certain "helper" methods to an entity. Take for example;

```
class Post {
   protected $tags;

   public function __construct() {
      $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
   }

   public function getTags() {
      return $this->tags;
   }

   public function addTag( $tagName ) {
      $tag = new Tag();
      $tag->setName( $tagName );

      $this->getTags()->add( $tag );
   }
}
```

In itself this works and it makes for clean code:

```
$post = new Post();
$post->addTag('Economy');
```

However, it becomes more problematic when a `Tag` is a Many to Many relationship and when adding a tag to a post we want to check if a tag already exists. E.g. a post might not have the tag 'Economy' so adding it to the post would be a new tag from the post's point of view. However, if the tag 'Economy' already exists in the database we have a problem. We want our entity to be as POPO as possible, i.e. not have references to entity managers or repositories.

What would be a good strategy to solve this problem?

Comment: Ahem, `$this->tags = new ArrayCollection();`

Comment: Thanks Phil. You can just edit my post right? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just talking to someone about this. This problem can actually be solved very elegantly by using life cycle events.

If a pre-persist life cycle event is implemented on the Post entity it's possible to get access to the entity manager from the life cycle event object. From the entity manager a repository can be requested and a method that checks the added tags for duplicates can be called.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PostRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Post {

    public function onPrePersist( LifecycleEventArgs $event ) {
       $entityManager = $event->getEntityManager();

       $repository = $entityManager->getRepository( get_class( $this ) );
       $repository->syncTags( $this );
    }

}
```

Meanwhile, in the `PostRepository`:

```
class PostRepository {

   public function syncTags( Post $post ) {
      $em = $this->getEntityManager();

      $tagsRepository = $em->getRepository('Tag');

      $tags = $post->getTags();

      foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
         $tagId = $tag->getId();

          if( empty( $tagId ) ) {
            $existingTag = $tagsRepository->findOneByName( $tag->getName() );

            if( ! empty( $existingTag ) ) {
               $tags->removeElement( $tag );
               $tags->add( $existingTag );
            }
         }
      }
   }

}
```

The above `syncTags` method basically loops through the Post tags. If a tag doesn't have an Id we can assume it never has been persisted before and is therefore added as a new tag. We then check if there already is a tag with that name. If not, we can persist it as a new tag otherwise we remove the duplicate and add the existing tag entity instead.

We can now keep our tag adding logic as simple as it should be:

```
$post = new Post();
$post->addTag('Economy');
```

If the 'Economy' tag already exists it will be used otherwise a new tag will be created.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried this when adding a tag to an existing post?  Using onPreUpdate?  I have had trouble with this sort of stuff when updating.  Because of this trouble I would add a createTag to the TagRepository which would either create a new tag or return an existing tag.  If onPreUdate works then I'll give it another shot because I agree that using life cycle event is the cleanest solution.

Comment: When I run my tests, I have fixtures to pre-populate some tags and then my tests will use some the existing tags and will also create new ones. My tests don't seem to fail and my db after the tests have run look exactly like I would expect it to look so I assume this works (unless my tests are wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do this outside the entity. For example...

```
class Post {
    // ...

    public function addTag(Tag $tag) {
        $this->getTags()->add($tag);
    }
}
```

and in say, a controller...

```
$post = new Post();

// I can't remember if this returns null for no records found or throws
// an exception. Needs checking
$tag = $em->getRepository('Tag')->findOneByName('Economy');
if ($tag == null) {
    $tag = new Tag();
    $tag->setName('Economy');

    $em->persist($tag); // don't need to do this if you use cascade persist
}
$post->addTag($tag);
```